# LaTeX, Image placed below ToC

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am trying to insert a picture (pdf) below a ToC, but when I do it through `\includepdf` it just appears on the next page. I have tried some absolute positioning, but haven't gotten any of them to work. The image is a quick mockup made in paint.net for what I am trying to achieve.
[image: Mockup]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: `\includegraphics`

Comment: `\includepdf` always starts a new page. `\includegraphics` does not, as @Johannes_B says.